# javascript / jQuery variable problem (possibly caching issue)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Standard AJAX query with jQuery:

```
var globalTitle = "";
var pages = ["a", "b", "c"];

for (var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
    createpage(pages[i]);
}

function createpage(title) {
    globalTitle=title;
    console.log (globalTitle); //All looks good here

    $.ajax({
        url: "createpage.php?id=" + title,
        context: document.body,
        success: success
    });
}
```

The success() function uses globaltitle which is why I had to declare it global.

In the success() function though console.log (globalTitle); constantly gives me "a". It's like the variable is assigned but is then cached every time success() is called.

Happens in FF 4 and Chrome 8. Any thoughts?

Edit: Here's the success() function:

```
function success(text) {
    console.log (globalTitle); // always "a"

    var div1 = "<div id=\"" + globalTitle + "\">";
    var text = "<a href=\"javascript:createpage('" + globalTitle + "')\">Retry</a> " + +text;
    var div2 = "</div>";

    if ($("#" + globalTitle).length) {
        $("#" + globalTitle).html(text);
    } else {
        $("#ajax").append(div1+text+div2);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post `success()`

Comment: how do you update the globalTitle looks like that should happen in your success method. Post that method and we should be able to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this (the `var xhr =` and `xhr.cpTitle` bits are key to this working). This is because `globalTitle` is overwritten each time a page is requested (all before any response is received), so it will always have the value of what was requested last:

```
function createpage(title) {

    console.log(title);

    var xhr = $.ajax({
        method: "post",
        url: "createpage.php",
        data: {
            id: title
        },
        context: document.body,
        success: success
    });

    xhr.cpTitle = title;

}

function success(data, status, xhr) {
    console.log(xhr.cpTitle);
}
```

Or this (note that `success()` is *inside* `createpage()`, avoiding this problem in another way by creating a closure):

```
function createpage(title) {

    function success(data, status, xhr) {
        console.log(title);
    }

    console.log(title);

    $.ajax({
        method: "post",
        url: "createpage.php",
        data: {
            id: title
        },
        context: document.body,
        success: success
    });

}
```

Comment: Tried the first solution, worked perfectly. Thank you so much. Still completely stumped as to the behaviour of my original code though.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that createpage is being called synchronously, but the success function will be called asynchronously so there is no guarantee what globaltitle will be set to when success runs. Try making globaltitle global to createpage instead of the entire script.

```
function createpage(title) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "createpage.php?id=" + title,
        context: document.body,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(title);

            //you could call your success function here and pass it title
            success(title);   
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: That was my first thought, but I tried using jquery with "async: false" so it makes one request at a time... same result. If I declare globaltitle in createpage(), success() can't find it